# Can P. falciparum and other malaria parasites be cultured and genetically engineered?

Tags: parasitology, malaria

I'm not a parasitologist, and I was wondering about the current state of malaria research. For instance, is it possible to culture P. *falciparum*? Are there techniques for genetic manipulation, editing or transfection (analogous to *in vitro* cell culture) ? Are there any major limitations to studying these parasites in culture?

Comment: If you are interested in a very brief update on malaria vaccine research, see Vaccine Outlook pg.s5, 6 March 2014 Nature.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is possible to culture plasmodia but they don't grow in a simple constituted medium. Usually RPMI supplemented with serum and erythrocytes is used for growing plasmodia ex-vivo. [This article](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC118084/) discusses the issues related to plasmodial culture in detail. The authors say that sometimes a certain growth stage (in particular gametocyte) is lost on prolonged cultivation. 
In the same paper it is discussed that the exo-erythrocytic (liver stage) plasmodia can be grown on cultured hepatoma cell lines.

Several transfection methods also exist. However, culturing is not a mandatory prerequisite for transfection. Usual methods like electroporation work for a wide spectrum of cell types (in-vivo electroporation is also becoming popular). You can refer to [this article](http://www.malariajournal.com/content/2/1/19) for a summary on different transfection methods for plasmodia.

A major limitation, in my opinion would be that the different life stages may not be reproduced in a single culture (as you can see that each stage thrives in a very different type of milieu).

Comment: I did a rotation in grad school in a malaria lab, and I seem to recall the PI saying (this was 10 years ago) that you can get a fairly homogenous population by timing when you infect the RBCs with the parasite. This way, they can get the reproducibility they need for multiple experiments.